# the derivative of a 3 variable function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

i don't know if it's correct but as i remember, the integral of  $\color{red}{df=dx + dy+dz} $
 is: $\color{red}{ f=x+y+z}$
and the differential of $\color{orange}{f } $ is $\color{orange}{d(f) =  {\partial f \over \partial x }dx +  {\partial f \over \partial y }dy +  {\partial f \over \partial z }dz }$ $\,\,$ so according to the red equation and orange equation, the integral of $d(f)$ should be $\color{green}{f={\partial f \over \partial x } +  {\partial f \over \partial y } +  {\partial f \over \partial z }}$. if we take $f=xyz^2$, with the orange equation df would be $df= yz^2dx + xz^2dy+2xyzdz $ and by the red equation, the f would be $\color {blue}{f=xyz^2+xyz^2 + xyz^2 }$ and it is wrong..
i'm super confused..

Comment: How is that compatible? By your last reasoning the first example would have to give $f=1+1+1$.

Comment: Functions of several variables don't quite work like this.

Comment: @LutzL i guess you didn't get my point. i edited it.

Comment: @SeanRoberson yes but which one of my equations is wrong?

Comment: Green is wrong. You can't integrate like that.

Comment: @SeanRoberson how come the green one is wrong and the red one is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red one is correct (except that you forgot the constant of integration), since it can be written as
$$
df = d(x+y+z)
,
$$
which means that $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z+C$.

But the green one is wrong, since the orange one is *not* (in general) the same thing as
$$
df = d\left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right)
.
$$

Comment: thanks, your answer helped me alot and i totally get your point. but what can we do to calculate the integral of the orange one? is there any solution or what?

Comment: The orange formula isn't really an equation to be solved for an unknown function $f$, it's an identity which holds for *all* (nice) functions $f$. (It can be taken as the definition of what the symbol $df$ *means*.)

Answer (score 1):

Integration works a little differently with functions of several variables. You can only integrate with respect to one variable at a time. So, if $f(x, y, z) = x + y + z,$ and the total derivative (differential) here is just the 1-form $$df = dx + dy + dz.$$

But, recovering $f$ is a little different. We cannot just simply integrate, and integrating one at a time doesn't quite do the job, as, for example,

$$ \int dx = x + g(y, z) $$

where $g$ is a function of $y$ and $z$ only. This function serves as the "constant" of integration, as taking the derivative with respect to $x$ will make $g$ vanish.

Answer (score 0):

The equation 
$$\color{orange}{
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,dz
}\tag1$$
is true in general; the equation
$$\color{red}{df = dx + dy + dz}\tag2$$
is a particular special case of Equation $(1)$ in which
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 1.$
And indeed one of the antiderivatives of Equation $(2)$ is $\color{red}{f = x + y + z}.$

It is not clear what the green equation,
$\color{green}{
f \stackrel?= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}},$
was intended to mean.
What it actually *does* say is easy to disprove;
for example, when
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 1$
the green equation says that
$$
f \stackrel?= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}
 = 1 + 1 + 1 = 3,
$$
whereas the actual solution for
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 1$
is $f = x + y + z + C,$ not the constant function $f = 3.$
What I suppose you really meant was
$$
f \stackrel?= \int\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx + \int\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy + \int\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,dz,\tag3
$$
since that produces your blue equation,
but Equation $(3)$ also is easy to disprove in the general case (as you have just done).
It is easy enough to show that Equation $(3)$ is true is when $f(x,y,z) = f_1(x) + f_2(y) + f_3(z),$
but in the general case we cannot count on being able to express $f$ as a sum of three independent components in that way.

But here is how we might find $f$ in the case where
$df= yz^2 \,dx + xz^2 \,dy + 2xyz \,dz$ as in your example;
that is, where
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =  yz^2,$
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = xz^2,$
and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 2xyz,$
by integrating over each of the variables $x,$ $y,$ and $z.$
We do this by finding the value of $f$ at a particular point, $f(x_1,y_1,z_1).$

First, setting $g(x) = f(x,0,0),$
we find that $g'(x) = \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{y=z=0} = 0,$ and
$$
g(x_1) = f(0,0,0) + \int_0^{x_1} g'(x) \,dx
 = f(0,0,0) + \int_0^{x_1} 0 \,dx = f(0,0,0).
$$
Therefore $f(x_1,0,0) = g(x_1) = f(0,0,0).$

Next, setting $h(y) = f(x_1,y,0),$
we find that $h'(y) = \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{x=x_1,z=0} = 0,$ and
$$
h(y_1) = f(x_1,0,0) + \int_0^{y_1} h'(y) \,dy
 = f(x_1,0,0) + \int_0^{y_1} 0 \,dx = f(x_1,0,0) = f(0,0,0).
$$
Therefore $f(x_1,y_1,0) = h(y_1) = f(0,0,0).$

Finally, setting $k(z) = f(x_1,y_1,z),$
we find that 
$k'(z) = \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right|_{x=x_1,y=y_1} = 2x_1y_1z,$ and
\begin{align}
k(z_1) &= f(x_1,y_1,0) + \int_0^{z_1} k'(z) \,dz\\
 &= f(x_1,y_1,0) + \int_0^{z_1} 2x_1y_1z \,dz\\
 &= f(x_1,y_1,0) + x_1y_1z_1^2 \\
 &= f(0,0,0) + x_1y_1z_1^2.
\end{align}
Therefore $f(x_1,y_1,z_1) = k(z_1) = f(0,0,0) + x_1y_1z_1^2.$
We can treat $f(0,0,0)$ as the constant of integration, and
obtain the particular antiderivative $f(x,y,z) = xyz^2$ from this result by setting $f(0,0,0) = 0.$

You could also get the same result in the same way by integrating $df$
along a path that starts at $(0,0,0),$ goes straight to $(x,0,0),$
then straight to $(x,y,0),$ and finally straight to $(x,y,z).$